# uploading file contents in python takes a long time

Tags: python, upload, multipart, httplib

I'm trying to upload files with the following code:

```
url = "/folder/sub/interface?"
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.mydomain.com')

def sendUpload(self):
    fields = []
    file1 = ['file1', '/home/me/Desktop/sometextfile.txt']
    f = open(file1[1], 'r')
    file1.append(f.read())
    files = [file1]
    content_type, body = self.encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)

    myheaders['content-type'] = content_type
    myheaders['content-length'] = str(len(body))

    upload_data = urllib.urlencode({'command':'upload'})
    self.connection.request("POST", self.url + upload_data, {}, myheaders)
    response = self.connection.getresponse()
    if response.status == 200:
        data = response.read()
        self.connection.close()
        print data
```

The encode_multipart_formdata() comes from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/

When I execute the method it takes a long time to complete. In fact, I don't think it will end.. On the network monitor I see that data is transferred, but the method doesn't end...

Why is that? Should I set a timeout somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be sending the body of your request to the server, so it's probably stuck waiting for `content-length` bytes to arrive, which they never do.

Are you sure that

```
self.connection.request("POST", self.url + upload_data, {}, myheaders)
```

shouldn't read

```
self.connection.request("POST", self.url + upload_data, body, myheaders)
```

?